# Close div if it is opened or open if it is close

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to implement below code to my project. But also I want to add an extra. If I click to button on opened(active) div It should close again. I'm doing this in a foreach loop. I 'll have many `#content` so it must be a class like `.content`.

What should I add or change on this nice code block?

All things needed below.

http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/4FKCa/

Comment: why you are not used .toggle and makes this code simple

Answer (score 0):

I replace some of your js. Now the buttons have an data-target attribute. You have to put a css selector in this attribute. When you click on a button, the js will use the data-target attribute to select the content that needs to be displayed.

```js
$("table .load-content").on("click", function () {
    var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    if ($(this).hasClass('content-loaded')) {
        $(currentRow).next().toggleClass('hidden');
    } else {
        var content = "<tr class='loaded-content'><td colspan='5'>" + $(this.getAttribute('data-target')).html() + "</td></tr>";
        $(content).insertAfter(currentRow);
        $(this).addClass('content-loaded');
    }
});
```

Here is the complete code :
http://jsfiddle.net/LLaaqqvr/5/

Why just not put the content you want to display directly in the table ? It will be really easier.

Comment: For each button, you have to specified a data-target, i only did it for the two first one.